# wrap overloading function with generics

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I want to wrap BitConverter with some extra functionalities. But I don't have to write out all the overloading functions like

```
BitConverter.GetBytes(int);
BitConverter.GetBytes(double);
...
```

Is there a way to write a single template function that wraps all the overloading functions? like

```
void GetBytes <T> (List<byte> byteList, T value) 
{
    ....
    byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    byteList.AddRange(result);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) for `IEnumerable<byte>` I suppose:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = new List<byte>();
        BitConverter.GetBytes(10).AddBytesToTarget(target);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(100d).AddBytesToTarget(target);
    }
}

static public class Extensions
{
    public static void AddBytesToTarget(this IEnumerable<byte> bytes, List<byte> target)
    {
        target.AddRange(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do it with generics since the overload resolution `BitConverter.GetBytes` will fail since `T` can be any type.

You could do it with `dynamic`:

```
void GetBytes(List<byte> byteList, dynamic value) {
    ....
    byte[] result = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    byteList.AddRange(result);
}
```

This will defer the overload resolution until runtime.  Of course this also pushes type checking so if an invalid type was used for value you would get a runtime exception instead of a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic type

Read this link of [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264741.aspx)